# Reverse animation in AndroidDialog on Back button pressed

Tags: java, android, animation, android-dialog

For now I have a problem with an animations in dialog. I've add animation like this:

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme_Animate;//setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogTheme_Animate);
        }
```

Animation looks like this:

```
<style name="DialogTheme.Animate" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
</style>
```

On back button pressed I have to change animation with reversed animation:

```
<style name="DialogTheme.Animate.Back" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

I call changing here:

```
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme_Animate_Back;
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
```

But animation isn't changed.

How I can change an animations in dialog when some event come? Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a little old, but will gonna help somebody, I think

You can hold Control pressed and click on `anim` code what you want reverse.
Will open a `xml` or class file.
So it's just you inverse the values of the code.

I hope be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to animate the view, then give a try to animate that programmatically.